# Проблема с офрмлением заказа товаров на сайте

Tags: joomla, cms

Проблема: невозможно осуществить покупку (оформление покупки) товара (`http://or-so.ru`). 
Товар добавляется в корзину, но при оформление заказа после заполнения формы обратной связи заказ не отправляется на почту и не появляется в админке. Происходит перенаправление на `/index.php?option=com_virtuemart`, хотя его не должно быть. Страница должна оставаться на `/index.php`. Но если корзина пуста, то форма отправляется и приходит на мой ящик как и положено.
На локальном сервере и на другом хостинге (`http://orso.seotag.by`) все работает.
Сайт на cms joomla 1.5 + virtuemart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут тебе надо проверить модуль "корзины". В настройках данного модуля должно быть "что потом делать"(грубо говоря)? Я на joomle сидел 2 года и в конце отказался. Проблема в том, что если какая-то ошибка, то фиг исправишь. Придется тебе дебажить пачку кодов PHP (это долго, поверь).

Comment: Нет, корзина не виновата и это ясно из моей проблемы.